# get xml data with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML

```
<person>
<FirstName>smname</FirstName>
<LastName>Kumari</LastName>
<Address>
<DoorNumber>556</DoorNumber>
<street>5th cross</street>
<City>ghcghfgh</City>
</Address>
<PhoneNumber>
<Mobile>2563</Mobile>
<Landline>64746</Landline>
<SkypeNumber>67567</SkypeNumber>
</PhoneNumber>
</person>
```

I am trying to get the value of `phonenumber->skypenumber` but getting an error.

Comment: Don't want to be negative but invalid XML with `getting an error` is not a good question!

Comment: thanks for cooment ,i didn't notice about the wrong xml,bcz of copy paste it was like now i hv edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your XML. The `<person>` tag is not written correctly, neither do you have a starting `<FirstName>` tag. Also there was a spelling error in `<PhoneNumber>`

Try this

```
<?php

$xml = <<< EOF
<person>
    <FirstName>Rashmi</FirstName>
    <LastName>Kumari</LastName>
    <Address>
        <DoorNumber>556</DoorNumber>
        <street>5th cross</street>
        <City>ghcghfgh</City>
    </Address>
    <PhoneNumber>
        <Mobile>2563</Mobile>
        <Landline>64746</Landline>
        <SkypeNumber>67567</SkypeNumber>
    </PhoneNumber>
</person>
EOF;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

var_dump((int) $xml->PhoneNumber->SkypeNumber);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.and sorry for wrong xml.becz of copy paste  it happen.

Comment: I have a same kind of Question,i am new to xml and json so can u plz let me know about it.                                Input:
 The following URL output details for employee #18 using JSON format:
http://demo.tools.krds.com/dispatch_ws.php?action=get&id=18&format=json
 This URL is slow to respond (~15 sec), it’s normal and must be handle accordingly in your code
Output:
 Output to the browser the name property of the employee #18
Guidelines
 Use CURL only
 Use correct timeouts and correct encoding

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in your post. Do you use the [simplexml_load_string](http://de.php.net/simplexml_load_string) function?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($yourstring);
$xml->person->PhoneNunber->SkypeNumber;
```